# cast base class pointer to one of several possible derived type pointer based on condition

Tags: c++, casting, rtti, derived-types

I have a base class `B` and several derived template classes `D<int>`, `D<float>`, `D<double>`, etc. (so more than ten)

In my program, I find a situation where I have a B pointer that I KNOW points to an instance one of the D specializations.  I also have a unique key that identifies the derived type.

So, I want to call the correct derived class method using my base class pointer and the unique type key.  I actually want to do this in several places, so the one solution I have come up with is not only ugly, but cumbersome.

**Is there a better way to access the derived class's members having a base pointer and a unique key in C++?**

I don't want to / can't modify the base class.  boost library is fair game.

Here is my potential code, but I'm not happy with replicating this everywhere I need to access a derived member function/variable.  All of this for one member function call?!!

```
B * bptr = ...
std::type_info * typekey = ...

if        (typekey == &typeid(D<float>) ) {
    D<float> * dptr = static_cast<D<float>*>(bptr);
    dptr->derivedMember();
} else if (typekey == &typeid(D<double>) ) {
    D<float> * dptr = static_cast<D<double>*>(bptr);
    dptr->derivedMember();
} else if (typekey == &typeid(D<int>) ) {
    D<float> * dptr = static_cast<D<int>*>(bptr);
    dptr->derivedMember();
}
```

Comment: Why not just have `derivedMember()` be a virtual function?

Comment: +1 to @KerrekSB, also if derivedMember is a member function of D (but not of B), you can introduce a base class C between D and B that adds derivedMember as a virtual function.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't see how making the derived members virtual will help in this case.  They don't exist in the base class.  I see that introducing an intermediary class may be an option.
I guess I was really hoping for something that would work given the existing class relationships, but I certainly won't' stick to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the `D<type>::` methods have the same name 'DerivedMember`, and I assume that the base class B does not declare this as virtual, can you change your hierachy from:

```
class B { etc. };

template<class T>
class D : public B
{
};
```

to:

```
class B { etc. };

class C : public B
{
 virtual void derivedMember() = 0;
};


template<class T>
class D : public C
{
public:
void derivedMember() { etc. };
};
```

Then you could have:

```
void f(C* c) /* or take a B* and do: C* c = static_cast<C*>(b); */
{    
  c->derivedMember();
}
```

Comment: I'm exploring this idea of creating an intermediary class in my code.  @Keith you probably meant the middle class to be `class C : public B` right?  At least, I'm not aware that you can declare both a template class an non-template class with the same name.  maybe you can...

Comment: I like your solution best, but found it a bit incomplete, so i edited.

Comment: Thanks. Certainly it is cleaner to have a different name for the intermediate anyway. Note that I see this is really a take on the "thin template" pattern - typically give a template a base class containing everything that does not need to be templated.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the correct way to handle the situation is by introducing a `virtual` method and having C++ dispatch the call correctly.

Since you cannot modify the base class, you can insert a new class with the virtual function and derive all the classes from the new class instead.

If you need to replicate this behavior with many functions, possibly ones that are not defined yet and the client code will provide, you can leverage the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).  In fact, if you cannot change the base class, you can at least use a Vistior-like technique to keep the tedious typekey checks in a single location and take out the actual operations to separate classes.  This will keep you from having to rewrite the typekey checks should another `derivedMember`-like function.

Answer (score 0):

I think Using dynamic_cast could solve the issue:

```
    B* base
    if(Class1* c1 = dynamic_cast<Class1*>(base))
    // it's a Class1*
    else if (Class2* c2 = dynamic_cast<Class2*>(base))
    // it's a Class2*
```