# How to have a class contain different class types and call the members of those objects held?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, rtti, derived-types

In my program, I find a situation where I want a `UserClass` that

1. is a container that can hold heterogenous types
2. can call member functions of the objects held.

The set of types that are held is limited and known at compile time.  In fact, all of the types are just different `template` specializations.

This code illustrates the situation:

```
class ArrayBase { /*etc.*/ };  // definition not changeable

template <class T>
class TypedArray : public ArrayBase  // definition not changeable
{
 /*more functionality needed by SpecializedArray.*/
}

template<class T>
class SpecializedArray : public TypedArray<T>
{
public:
 void newFunctionalityMember() { /*etc.*/ };
};

class UserClass
{
    addArray( arrayElmentTypeEnum_t t)
    {
        switch(t) {
        case float_id:
            _elementArrays.push_back( new SpecializedArray<float>() );
            break;
        case double_id:
            _elementArrays.push_back( new SpecializedArray<double>() );
            break;
        default:
            break;  
    }

    void doSomethingWithASpecializedArray(int num)
    {
       // using _elementArrays[num], call the correct newFunctionalityMember()

    }

    private:
        std::vetor<storagePtr_t> _elementArrays;
}
```

Without some pleading, I don't have flexibility to change `ArrayBase` or `TypedArray`.
I have left `storagePtr_t` type undefined, as what type it should be is a key part of my question.

I can think of one solution, illustrated below.  But what a pain!  This is a lot of code to have anywhere in `UserClass` that I need to access the element members.  **Is there a better way?**

boost library is fair game.

**my technique:**

`storagePtr_t` is `ArrayBase*`, 
`arrayElmentTypeEnum_t` would be a `std::type_info*`

```
UserClass::doSomethingWithASpecializedArray(int num)
{
// these two both uniquely identified by num.
storagePtr_t * bptr = _elementArrays[num];
arrayElmentTypeEnum_t typekey = ...

    if        (typekey == &typeid(SpecializedArray<float>) ) {
        D<float> * dptr = static_cast<SpecializedArray<float>*>(bptr);
        dptr->newFunctionalityMember();
    } else if (typekey == &typeid(SpecializedArray<double>) ) {
        D<float> * dptr = static_cast<SpecializedArray<double>*>(bptr);
        dptr->newFunctionalityMember();
    } else if (typekey == &typeid(SpecializedArray<int>) ) {
        D<float> * dptr = static_cast<SpecializedArray<int>*>(bptr);
        dptr->newFunctionalityMember();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I found my earlier [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736923/cast-base-class-pointer-to-one-of-several-possible-derived-type-pointer-based-on) did not contain enough detail of my case at hand to flush out a helpful solution.

Comment: Why can't you make `UserClass` also a `template` ? That will save you from lot of cluttering, isn't  it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce a new base class that defines the interface you want to invoke:

```
class SpecializedArrayBase {
public:
    virtual ~SpecializedArrayBase() {}
    virtual void newFunctionalityMember() = 0;
};
```

and then derive your array type from this base:

```
template<class T>
class SpecializedArray : public TypedArray<T>, public SpecializedArrayBase
{
public:
    void newFunctionalityMember() { /*etc.*/ };
};
```

You can then store objects in your vector by the new base type `SpecializedArrayBase`:

```
typedef SpecializedArrayBase* storagePtr_t;
```

Since the base class defines the function you want to invoke, you can avoid all of the casting and invoke it through the base pointer:

```
void doSomethingWithASpecializedArray(int num)
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < _elementArrays.size(); ++i) {
       _elementArrays[i]->newFunctionalityMember();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DRH!  this is working nicely. I wasn't thinking about inheriting from two classes.
It is probably worth pointing out that `SpecializedArrayBase` should have a virtual destructor, or the `UserClass` destructor should be very explicit about making sure the `SpecializedArray` destructors are called.

Comment: Thanks @NoahR, I've added a virtual dtor to the example.